# Call Api Controller From Different Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

[image: Project architecture]

MVC(View) and Web API(APIcontroller) in different Project

how can i call value controller from different class library?
Demowebapicontroller class library contain all controllers
Demowebapi consist all view

Answer (score 0):

Just refactor your `Value` controller to use methods and logic from another class which you can also instantiate from another controller by adding project references between the assemblies.